# DateTime Parsing in XSLT Xp20

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am having the Date  field as below

```
    <Input>
<date>08/26/2020</date>
</Input>
```

i would need to parse it as like below

```
<date>2020-08-26</date>
```

I have tried using below xpath funtion in XSLT, which is not producing any result

```
xp20:format-dateTime(/Input/date,'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]')
```

Any help here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replace` you can reorder the components, if you want to create an XSLT/XPath `xs:date`, additionally use the constructor function:

```
  <xsl:template match="date">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(replace(., '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', '$3-$1-$2'))"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, extract sub strings, and re-join them as needed.

```
<date><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-after(substring-after(date/text(),'/'),'/'), '-', substring-before(date/text(),'/'), '-', substring-before(substring-after(date/text(),'/'),'/'))" /></date>
```

or better use a template for this:

```
<xsl:template name="format_date">
        <xsl:param name="date" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat( substring($date, 7, 2),'.',substring($date, 5, 2), '.', substring($date, 1, 4), ', ', substring($date, 9, 2),':',substring($date, 11, 2),'h' )" />
    </xsl:template>
```

and pass the date as param (with-param).

which'll give you the desired `<date>2020-08-26</date>`